# Repeat image on a fixed background, Cocos2D?

Tags: background, cocos2d-iphone

I'm new to Cocos2d, does anyone know how to create a background that would be one fixed screen (no scrolling), with a small image just repeated to the whole size of the screen?

Comment: search for GL_REPEAT or use a tilemap

Answer (score 0):

Your best option (much less memory and time intensive) would be to create a larger background image based on the small one you speak of. Its fairly easy to do in photoshop. Follow these instructions:

1. Open the base image in photoshop.
2. Select the area around the image.
3. Click Edit->Define Pattern and save the new pattern
4. Create a new image (320x480 portrait iPhone, 640x960 portrait retina)
5. Click Edit->Fill and select pattern, then select the pattern you created.
6. Save the image and add it as your background inside the game.